# Not able to change the button size

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am not able to change the button size even though I am using a CSS class to change the width. 
The form which has the button and the content are placed in a `<div>`row class. so that they appear side by side.

This is the part of my
 code:

```css
.row.someDiv{
  margin-left: 0px;
  margin-right: 0px;
  max-width: initial;
}
input[type="text"]{
  border: none;
  border-bottom: 1px solid;
  width: 250px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  background: transparent;
}
.button-size{
  width: 100px;
  padding-bottom: 20px;
  
}
```

```html
<div class="row someDiv">
  <div class="col-xs-8">
   <br/>  
   <label>
     <input type="text" class="text-line" placeholder="Name" required></label><br/>
   <label><input type="text" class="text-line"  placeholder="Email Address" required></label><br/>
   <label><input type="text" class="text-line"  placeholder="phone number"></label><br/>
     <label><input id="message-size"  type="text" placeholder="Message"></label><br/>
    <button type="submit" class="button-size space btn btn-block btn-primary"><i class="fa fa-paper-plane">Submit</i></button>
 </div>
 <div class="col-xs-4">
   <p class="content-style"> Want to get in touch? please fill up the form and I'll revert back soon.
  </div>
</div>
```

[image: Button]

Comment: I think in `.button-size` class the width should be `width: 100px;`

Comment: 'width: 100x;' change to  'width: 100px;'

Comment: Hi @Animus it was a typing error here and not on my webpage. I have attached the snapshot of the portion for your better understanding. Please look into it and let me know what can be done.

Comment: @GauravThantry
Thank you for this info. 
You can try adding 'display: block',  if this property is changed from somewhere else. Otherwise you can just use 'max-width: 100px'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you’re using **bootstrap**, in which case your `btn-block` class on the button makes the button a “block-level element” (equivalent to giving it the css `{display: block;}`)
Block-level elements fill 100% of horizontal space and push any other elements down the page to make room.

Answer (score 1):

syntax problem `x` to `px`

```
.button-size{
  width: 100px;
  padding-bottom: 20px;

}
```

Comment: Thank you for your quick response @Lalji Tadhani. That was the typing error in stackover flow. It is still not working. I have added a snapshot for your reference.

Comment: remove this class "btn-block"

Comment: @GauravThantry What exactly do you want in there ?

Comment: other than change this class <div class="col-xs-6"> & change this css input[type="text"]{ width:100%;}

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. The button must be enclosed in the `<label>` element. I am using this for now. Even though I don't understand why can't the button be shrunk without `<label>`. It had worked for me previously. Please feel free to pitch in answers.